# Using Jenkins and irrFuscator - doesn't get past obfuscateing the source

Tags: ant, jenkins

I dont know if anyone out there will have tried using Jenkins / Ant / irrFuscator combo - hopefully someone has and can provide some direction.

The problem is I start a build in jenkins, everything seems to be building fine until I hit the part of my build where the ant file calls irrFuscator.  At this point Jenkins still says that it is trying to build the project (the building wheel keeps spinning) but nothing seems to be happening in irrFuscator.

I have checked Task Manager and irrFuscator is taking no cpu time.

If I force quit irrFuscator from Task Manager the build fails - so jenkins knows of irrFuscators existance.

I have run the build outside of jenkins and everything seems to build fine.

Build logs can be provided but there is no useful information there - it just says its waiting.

If anyone has any ideas I would love to hear from you! And if further info is needed please feel free to ask.

Thanks for taking the time to read!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never used irrFuscator, but first things to check:

- Make sure you are running Jenkins in the foreground (and not as a background service). The simplest way to do it is with `java -jar jenkins.war [other options]` command (refer to [this document](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Starting+and+Accessing+Jenkins)).
- Make sure that you run Jenkins as the same user as you run it when it works outside Jenkins.

Comment: 10 points for java -jar jenkins.war -- why the hell would they give you the option of 'jenkins start'....